# Bundle is not storing and updating value on restart

Tags: android, android-bundle

As normal, I am trying to store my location name on a bundle and use it on hot start as:

```
    public class LocFragment extends Fragment {
      private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
      public String location;//="No location name found";

       //to be called by the MainActivity as:
       //@Override
       //public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        //switch (pos) {
        //    case 0:
        //      return new LocFragment();
        //    case 2:....
      public LocFragment() {
      // Required empty public constructor
      }
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
          location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
    //      Snackbar.make(getView(), location, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("location  "+location);

          //mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }else{
          System.out.println("NULL SI");
        }
      }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ....
     List<Address> addresses = null;
     Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
     try {
      addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
       latlang.Lat,
       latlang.Lang,
       1);
     } catch (IOException ioException) {
     // Catch network or other I/O problems.
     errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
     // Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
     Snackbar.make(getView(), errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
    // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
    errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
    Snackbar.make(getView(),
      "Illegal Latitude = " + latlang.Lat + ", Longitude = " +
          latlang.Lang, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
     if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("Adress Empty No Adress Found");// Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       location = "Restart the app";
     }
  } else {
  location = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
  System.out.println("AM I GETTING Location"+location);
}


  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (location != null) {
      outState.putCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME, location);
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
  }
```

Now, I am hoping this situation:

1. on cold start of the app, the savedInstanceState will be null and print `"NULL SI"`. In this step, when it has got a location name, that will be added to `"KEY_LOCATION_NAME"` on `onSaveInstanceState`
2. On the second time, on a hot start, this will be added to the location.

But this is not I am getting.

From log, on **cold start**:

```
I/System.out: NULL SI
I/System.out: Adress Empty No Adress Found
```

it takes the address in this step, then:
**@1st Hot start**

```
 I/System.out: NULL SI
 I/System.out: AM I GETTING LocationMountain View
```

**@2nd Hot start** (Just to confirm, it shows same thing even when location is known):

```
 I/System.out: NULL SI
 I/System.out: AM I GETTING LocationMountain View
```

What I am missing here?

**UPDATE**
Just checked that `onSaveInstanceState` is actually **never** called by the code. May this be the reason? How can I call this?

**UPDATE: MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

       /*
        NavigationView
        */
        ImageButton leftNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.left_nav);
        ImageButton rightNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.right_nav);
            leftNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              int tab = pager.getCurrentItem();
                if (tab > 0) {
                    tab--;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(tab);
                } else if (tab == 0) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(tab);
                }
                }
            });

            rightNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int tab = pager.getCurrentItem();
                tab++;
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab);
                }
            });

    }


    public void showDateDialog() {
        DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
        CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

 /*   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
//        int id = menu.getItem(int );
//        if (id = )
        return true;
    }*/

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                  //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                  return new LocFragment();
                case 2:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, instance 1");
                case 1:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();
                case 3:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                default:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, default");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you add data in addresses ?

Comment: addresses was something I did not think important, because I was just interested in location. But its added now.

Comment: now your problem solved or not?

Comment: :-o how? there is the same problem.

Comment: declare addresses as global

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem either. Also I dont understand, Location is read correctly inside the code, as in "AM I Getting Location". So what purpose it will solve by changing the scope of addresses.

Comment: @BaRud how is this fragment added to your activity?

Comment: @BenP.: the code is updated...at the top, I have added the public method that the activity calls

Comment: One thing: I have another `onBundleSavedInstance` on another fragment class. is it possible that that fragment is overriding this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002318/is-googlemap-inherently-parcelable is the fragment I am talking about, and the bundle for 2nd instance is working.

Comment: @BenP.  I have just found that the onsaveinstancestate is never called. I have updated the question. Can you kindly check?

Comment: @BaRud I need to see the Activity code, not just the Fragment code that the activity calls. It's important to see exactly how you show this fragment, since doing it wrong can cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @BenB: the comment above to locfragment is the call. Do you want to see the full activity?

Comment: @BenP.: Activity is added. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @BenP. any clue?